LG GWL207FBQA ice water dispenser unit leak
Picked up a second hand fridge freezer but the sellers neglected to mention there is a leak from the ice and water dispenser unit.
It isn’t the dispenser section itself but behind it. Water is seeping below the dispenser unit.
I’ve removed fascia and cleaned and serviced everything I can.
Is there a way for me to remove this other part?
Any other fixes?

For a cheap old fridge disconnect the water and buy a filter jug because parts are expensive, often more than a used fridge.  OTOH if it's a broken hose you could fix it with parts from a hardware store so worth trying.  Look up your model, or similar ones from the same maker (or other makers, many share designs) on YouTube. There are lots of tutorial videos showing how to disassemble and fix common problems. For parts enter your model number in any appliance parts web site, and find the parts diagram there.

We can't diagnose appliance problems in this forum, your question is much too vague.  But if you learn on youtube and do as much as you can but then still cannot get the door apart, add the model number here, add photos of both sides of the door, describe where you're getting stuck and you should get some help.

I would recommend the PartsDr forum.
